# Can I map within a map like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am learning react/jsx and I have come across a dilemna.

I wanted to "simplify" by trying to create a map within a map, I thought I knew what I was doing, but apparently it doesn't like it.

I have the following object:

```
defaultState = {
  userName: "",
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  bio: "",
  country: "",
  notifications: [
    {
      label: "Newsletter",
      value: "newsletter",
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      label: "Updates",
      value: "updates",
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      label: "Reports",
      value: "reports",
      checked: false,
    },
  ]
};
```

And essentially I wanted to make a map of the notifications within the defaultState data. So that way I have a card with the following info

1. firstName={user.firstName}
2. lastName={user.lastName}
3. userName={user.userName}
4. email={user.email}
5. bio={user.bio}
6. {user.notifications[0].value} ={user.notifications[0].checked}
7. {user.notifications[1].value} ={user.notifications[1].checked}
8. {user.notifications[2].value} ={user.notifications[2].checked}

So it would look something like this

- Username: ausername123
- First Name: A.
- Last Name: W.
- Email: blahblah@gmail.com
- Bio: There is a description
- Newspaper Notif: True
- Updates Notif: False
- Reports Notif: True

So far I have written a map of the following

```
{this.state.users.map((user) => {
  return(
    <User
      key={user.userName}
      firstName={user.firstName}
      lastName={user.lastName}
      userName={user.userName}
      email={user.email}
      bio={user.bio}
      country={user.country}
      {user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)}
    />
  )
})}
```

However the line
{user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)} came up with an error of the following

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "..." (31:33)

> 31 |                                 {user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)}
> |                                  ^
> 32 |                             />
> 33 |                             )
> 34 |                         })}

Due to a request, this is what I am trying to run on User.js. Where essentially I want to create three additional props labeled

- newsletter
- updates
- reports
  They happen to be notifications[].label and I want to give them a value either true or false depending on which checkbox is checked off.

```
const User = ({userName, firstName, lastName, email, bio, country, newsletter, updates, reports}) => (
        <Component>
            <Header>User Details of {firstName} {lastName}</Header>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Username:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{userName}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Email:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{email}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Bio:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{bio}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Country:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{country}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Newsletter:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{newsletter}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Updates:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{updates}</Item>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Text>
                    <strong>Reports:</strong>
                </Text>
                <Item>{reports}</Item>
            </Field>
        </Component>
    );
```

Comment: you have to assign the notifications to a prop that you will handle in the `User` component; you should change `{user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)}` to `notifications={user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)}`

Comment: @secan Write that as an answer

Comment: @slebetman, sure, no problem; I did not think it had the "dignity" of a proper answer, given the fact that it is not the solution to some obscure problem and can be found in or deduced from the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the notifications to a prop that you will handle in the User component; you should change

`{user.notifications.map((n) => n.value = n.checked)}`

to

`notifications={user.notifications.map((n) => ({[n.value]: n.checked}))}`

Then the `notifications` prop in the `User` component will look like:

```js
[
  { newsletter: false },
  { updates: false },
  { reports: false } 
]
```

If you want an object, instead, you should use `reduce`:

`notifications={user.notifications.reduce((obj, n) => ({ ...obj, [n.value]: n.checked })), {}}`

will give you

```js
{
  newsletter: false,
  updates: false,
  reports: false
}
```

But really, as you already have `user.notifications`, the most logic and straightforward thing to do would be passing it as prop (`notifications={user.notifications}`) and manipulate it in the `User` component, if necessary.

### [UPDATE]

Following the update of your question with the code of the `User` component, this should work as a complete solution:

#### in the parent component:

```js
//...
{this.state.users.map(user => (
  <User
    key={user.userName}
    firstName={user.firstName}
    lastName={user.lastName}
    email={user.email}
    bio={user.bio}
    country={user.country}
    notifications={user.notifications}
  />
))}
//...
```

or, if you are passing all or most of the attributes of the `user` object, simply pass the entire object

```js
//...
{this.state.users.map(user => (
  <User
    key={user.userName}
    user={user}
  />
))}
//...
```

#### in the User component:

```js
const User = ({userName, firstName, lastName, email, bio, country, notifications}) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Header>User Details of {firstName} {lastName}</Header>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Username:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{userName}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Email:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{email}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Bio:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{bio}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Country:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{country}</Item>
      </Field>
      {notifications.map(n => (
        <Field>
          <Text><strong>{n.label}</strong></Text>
          <Item>{ n.checked ? 'true' : 'false' }</Item>
        </Field>
      ))}
    </Component>
  );
};
```

or, if you passed the entire user object from the parent:

```js
const User = ({user}) => {
  const {userName, firstName, lastName, email, bio, country, notifications} = user;
  return (
    <Component>
      <Header>User Details of {firstName} {lastName}</Header>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Username:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{userName}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Email:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{email}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Bio:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{bio}</Item>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Text><strong>Country:</strong></Text>
        <Item>{country}</Item>
      </Field>
      {notifications.map(n => (
        <Field>
          <Text><strong>{n.label}</strong></Text>
          <Item>{ n.checked ? 'true' : 'false' }</Item>
        </Field>
      ))}
    </Component>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well it is not breaking down, which is a good start. I will try to figure out the rest of why the true/false values are not showing.

Comment: Well, with the you are using for the inner map makes no sense: `n.value` is a string, `n.check` is a boolean; they will never be equals... especially if you try to compare them using an assignament (`=`) instead of a comparison (`===` or `==`)

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that issue too

Comment: I tried toString() the value of n.checked so that way it would be displayed something like a prop named newspaper, which is notifications[0].value would hold the string statement of "true" or "false".

Idk if that is how it works.

Comment: @AlbertWang, no that is not how it works. It wouls be easier to help you if you update your question with the code of the `User` component

Comment: Okay I will do that, give me a min.

Comment: I saw your updated answer, it is very informative. I think I would take your suggestion and try to do the straightforward approach you suggested.

Comment: @AlbertWang, I further updated the answer, referring to your component code; I hope that helps. ;)

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR. I totally forgot I could do that now I feel silly. Thank you very much, now I can sleep.